# Where/When the interpreter generates the graphic output, seaborn vs matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

My question is about using seaborn and matplotlib together, common practice in many works.

I don't understand what command actually generates the graphic output...

#### How does the Python interpreter know when to plot the graph?

I used to think `sns` was drawing the graph, since it would be the last command before a graphic output:

```
plt.title("Monthly Visitors to Avila Adobe")
plt.xlabel("Date")

sns.lineplot(data=museum_data['Avila Adobe'],label='Avila Adobe')
```

But I found others examples with inverted calls, `plt` in last, and the graphic output displayed only after the `plt` call:

```
sns.lineplot(data=museum_data['Avila Adobe'],label='Avila Adobe')

plt.title("Monthly Visitors to Avila Adobe")
plt.xlabel("Date")
```

The two codes above do exact the same graphics.

I understand seaborn is build on top of matplotlib.

But,

#### I don't understand where/when the code generates the graphic output: after the `sns` or after the `plt`?

What statement draw the graph?

If my rationalization is wrong, pls clarify why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Seaborn` and `Matplotlib` are two of `Python's` most powerful visualization libraries. `Seaborn` uses fewer syntax and has stunning default themes and `Matplotlib` is more easily customizable through accessing the classes.

**`Seaborn`**

The [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/introduction.html) package was developed based on the [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) library. It is used to create more attractive and informative statistical graphics. While `seaborn` is a different package, it can also be used to develop the attractiveness of `matplotlib` graphics.

To answer your question, When we load `seaborn` into the session, everytime a `matplotlib` plot is executed, `seaborn's` default customizations are added. However, a huge problem that troubles many users is that the `titles` can overlap. Combine this with `matplotlib's` only confusing naming convention for its titles it becomes a nuisance. Nevertheless, the `attractive visuals` still make it usable for every Data Scientist's work.

In order to get the titles in the fashion that we want and have more customizability, We need to use the `seaborn` & `matplotlib` structure . Note that this is only necessary if we use subtitles in our plots. Sometimes they are necessary so it is better to have it on hand. Refer below code for more details.

**`matplotlib` style plot :**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# using some dummy data for this example
xs = np.random.randint( 0, 10, size=10)
ys = np.random.randint(-5, 5,  size=10)

# plot the points
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
fig.suptitle('Matplotlib with Python', fontsize='x-large', fontweight='bold')
plt.subplot(121)
plt.scatter(xs,ys,c='b') # scatter graph plotted from this line
plt.grid()  
plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(xs,ys,'bo--') # line graph plotted from this line
plt.grid()
```

[image: MATPLOTLIB]

**`Seaborn` style plot :**

```py
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('Seaborn with Python', fontsize='x-large', fontweight='bold')
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.87)
#This is used for the main title. 'figure()' is a class that provides all the plotting elements of a diagram. 
#This must be used first or else the title will not show.fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.85) solves our overlapping title problem.

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)

fontdict={'fontsize': 14,
        'fontweight' : 'book',
        'verticalalignment': 'baseline',
        'horizontalalignment': 'center'}

ax.set_title('Scatter Plot Tutorial', fontdict=fontdict)
#This specifies which plot to add the customizations. fig.add_sublpot(121) corresponds to top left plot no.1 
 

plt.plot(xs, ys, 'bo' ) # scatter graph plotted from this line in seaborn with matplotlib command & seaborn style
plt.xlabel('x-axis', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('yaxis', fontsize=14)

ax = fig.add_subplot(122)
fontdict={'fontsize': 14,
        'fontweight' : 'book',
        'verticalalignment': 'baseline',
        'horizontalalignment': 'center'}

ax.set_title('Line Plot Tutorial', fontdict=fontdict)
sns.lineplot(xs, ys) # line graph plotted from this line in seaborn with seaborn command & seaborn style
plt.xlabel('x-axis', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('yaxis', fontsize=14);
```

[image: SEABORN]

Now compare both plots `stylewise` and please read code **`comments`** carefully.

**source**

1. [Python seaborn tutorial](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/04/data-visualization-python-matplotlib-seaborn.html#:%7E:text=Seaborn%20and%20Matplotlib%20are%20two,of%20packages%20for%20plotting%20data.)

Comment: Hi. I'm testing your considerations. And I see the style difference. But, and that is where I'm confused, WHEN the graph is plotted? How does the interpreter know when plot the graph?

Comment: In the above example, in `matplotlib` graphics generated on `plt.scatter(xs,ys,c='b')` this line. and in `seaborn` graphics generated on `sns.lineplot(xs, ys)` this line. That is why i combined both in `seaborn` example. When you generate `figure` object, its an empty object with 0 axes. In `seaborn`, you can also use `matplotlib` functions as well.

Comment: @marcio : I had added comments in my code to show you where exactly it generate the plots.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question 6 months ago, so, now I'm 6 months more experienced!

**How does the Python interpreter know when to plot the graph?

I don't understand where/when the code generates the graphic output: after the sns or after the plt?**

What I learn:
Well, I was used to a approach where after a given command and I get a response.
But that is no the case when working with graphics in Python, specially when using a notebook...
Actually, using `matplotlib`, `sns`, etc, we can, in a **cumulative way**, prepare many aspects **before** actually output the graphic.
And many commands (functions, methods) are capable to do the real display, but it is the last "complete" command (my interpretation here) does the job.
So, since they are consistent, the order is not a problem.
Sure, we need to assure the good logic!

It was that I would like to understand.

The @jay-patel answer helped me to think about it, he give me good examples.